# Tratar caracteres especiales al usar el comando run en Julia

Tags: julia

necesito ejecutar un comando usando la función `run` en Julia, pero me he encontrado con el problema del carcater `&`, lo que quiero hacer específicamente es usar la expresión:

`pdflatex prueba1 >log & prueba1.pdf`

que genera un archivo pdf (prueba1.pdf) de un código Latex, la expresión `>log` evita mostrar las lineas de compilación (en vez de eso escribe estas lineas en un archivo `log`), una vez terminado abre el archivo generado, en una linea de comandos normal se ejecuta sin problema, pero al ejecutarlo desde Julia no me funciona:

```
julia> run(`pdflatex prueba1 >log & prueba1.pdf`);
```

me muestra todas las lineas de compilación y no abre el archivo generado (al parecer ignora todo luego del caracter `>`) , he buscado y probado algunas cosas sin exito.

Refiriendome al manual de Julia en la sección [Pipelines](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/running-external-programs/#Pipelines-1), dice literalmente:

> Shell metacharacters, such as |, &, and >, need to be quoted (or escaped) inside of Julia's backticks:

Lo que da a entender que estos caracteres necesitan ser acotados entre comillas simples o ignorados dentro de las, digamos, comillas inclinadas de Julia (``), pero:

```
julia> run(`pdflatex prueba1 '>'log '&' prueba1.pdf`);
```

obtengo el mismo comportamiento anterior. Creo que Julia no interpreta como debería estos símbolos y es por eso que no funciona. Lo mejor que he logrado es ejecutar la linea abriendo otra ventana del cmd con:

```
julia> run(`cmd /c start pdflatex prueba1  & prueba1.pdf`);
```

he quitado el `>log` porque ahora las líneas se imprimen en otra ventana, lo que pasa ahora es que al parecer el comando para abrir el archivo no espera a que termine de ejecutarse el primer comando, lo que me da como resultado, que se abra el archivo sin actualizar, o en caso de que el archivo no exista todavía, el mensaje de archivo no encontrado.

¿Hay alguna forma de manejar esto?, en términos generales lo que deseo es:

**Ejecutar dos comandos, evitar que se impriman las líneas que el primer comando arroje y esperar a que termine el primer comando antes de iniciar el segundo.**

Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

intentando comprender mejor el manual de Julia en la sección [running external programs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/running-external-programs/), creo que he coseguido lo que quería. El equivalente de:

```
pdflatex prueba1 >log
```

en Julia sería:

```
julia> run(pipeline(`pdflatex prueba1`,stdout="log.txt"));
```

y el equivalente de `&` sería escribir el otro comando en otra linea, i.e.:

```
julia> run(pipeline(`pdflatex prueba1`,stdout="log.txt",stderr="err.txt"));
julia> run(`cmd /c start prueba1.pdf`);
```

`stderr="err.txt"`, crea y escribe el archivo `"err.txt"` con los posibles errores o advertencias que se arrojen en la compilación, con esto el REPL quedaría libre de cualquier tipo de lineas que arroje el comando ejecutado (aunque en algunos casos puede ser necesario ver estas líneas, ahora que he estado probando algunas cosas), por último, para abrir el archivo es imperativa la apertura de otra instancia del cmd con `cmd /c start`, ya que si solo pongo el nombre del archivo sale un error.

Cabe mencionar que estas dos lineas están dentro de una función, de querer ejecutarlas manualmente el problema nunca hubiese existido, ya que es fácil esperar a que termine de ejecutar una línea y pasar a ejecutar la siguiente.